# Try to get Textbox.SelectionStart value before losing focus

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

A simple question but I still cannot find any solution for this situation.
I want to get the caret position before the text triggers LostFocus event, because if I get the value in the LostFocus event method, it already reset to 0.
Help me find out this problem please.

Thank you in advance,
Johnny Sayasane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TextBox class supports an event called "SelectionChanged" , you could try to use this event to set an integer to get the caret's position, check this code:

```
    private int CaretPosition;

    private void textBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CaretPosition = textBox.SelectionStart;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, the same as what I was doing a moment ago! Thanks again :)